# How to fill a vector in class with objects of different class

Tags: c++, class, c++11, vector, constructor

I'm working on a project in which I have to create a class of workers (with some basic info) and put them all in vector.

I've found a solution which works for me, but I'm curious is there a better way to do this? So, I'm just looking for different implementation of my code.

This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<iterator>

class worker
{
  private:
    std::string _name;
    int _age;
    double _pay;
  public:
    worker() : _age{0}, _pay{0.0} {}
    worker(std::istream& entry){ input(entry); }

    std::istream& input(std::istream& x){ return x >> _name >> _age >> _pay ; }

    const std::string& get_name() { return _name; }
    const int& get_age(){ return _age; }
    const double& get_pay(){ return _pay;}
};

class vecworkers
{
  private:
    std::vector<worker> vec_workers;
  public:
    void input(std::istream& x)
    {
      worker temp;
      while(temp.worker::input(x))
      vec_workers.push_back(temp);

    }

    void output(std::ostream& x)
    {
      worker temp;
      for( std::vector<worker>::const_iterator it = vec_workers.begin() ; it != vec_workers.end() ; ++it )
      {
        temp = *it ;
        std::cout << temp.get_name() << " "<< temp.get_age() << " " << temp.get_pay() << std::endl;
      }
    }

};

int main()
{
  vecworkers w1;
  w1.input(std::cin);
  w1.output(std::cout);
  return 0;
}
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Why are you naming methods `input` and `output` instead of overloading the `<<` and the `>>` operators? What is the purpose of the `vecworkers` class? I mean just for reading and writing out data in a trivial and simple loop it is quite pointless.

Comment: @CMate I've just tried to make my question as readable as possible, vecworkers class does some other things too, but I'm asking just about this.

Comment: This would make a good question for codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT 1:** The title of your question is a bit misleading

---

**ANSWER:**

Well, since you tagged C++11, I am assuming I can use C++11 features here... so:

Some advice on your code:

- The getters in `worker` class returns `const reference`, should be marked `const` functions, so you have:

  ```
  const std::string& get_name() const { return _name; }
  const int& get_age() const { return _age; }
  const double& get_pay() const { return _pay;}
  ```
- Again, theres no point returning a `const int&` and `const double&`, (though I believe optimizers will figure this out).

  ```
  const std::string& get_name() const { return _name; }
  int get_age() const { return _age; }
  double get_pay() const { return _pay;}
  ```
- You may want to think about overloading the insertion and extraction operators `<<` and `>>` for `worker`. It conveys the message.
- Other than ending the input loop, how do you handle `istream` failures based on wrong formatting? You may want to think about that. Even without failures, a single wrong formatting **will** screw up inputs of your entire vecworkers

---

- First alternative (no design change, just cleanup... *but remember, you must make the above `const` corrections for this to work*):

---

```
class vecworkers
{
  private:
    std::vector<worker> vec_workers;
  public:
    void input(std::istream& x)
    {
        for(worker w; w.input(x); vec_workers.push_back(w));
    }

    void output(std::ostream& x)
    {
        for(const auto& w : vec_workers)
            std::cout << w.get_name() << " " << w.get_age() << " " << w.get_pay() << std::endl;
    }

};
```

- Second alternative (moved printing responsibility... or you may want to have a class responsible for printing if you are gonna have different styles)

---

```
class worker
{
  private:
    std::string _name;
    int _age;
    double _pay;
  public:
    worker() : _age{0}, _pay{0.0} {}
    worker(std::istream& entry){ input(entry); }

    std::istream& input(std::istream& x){ return x >> _name >> _age >> _pay ; }
    std::ostream& output(std::ostream& x) const { return x << _name << _age << _pay; }

    const std::string& get_name() const { return _name; }
    int get_age() const { return _age; }
    double get_pay() const { return _pay;}
};

class vecworkers
{
  private:
    std::vector<worker> vec_workers;
  public:
    void input(std::istream& x)
    {
        for(worker w; w.input(x); vec_workers.push_back(w));
    }

    void output(std::ostream& x)
    {
        for(const auto& w : vec_workers)
            w.output(std::cout);    //since you didn't overload insertion operator <<
    }

};
```

---

- Third alternative?... this is quite trivial to compound ... so, with a bit of cleanup your solution works.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: It was a rookie mistake returning const int& and const double&, there is no point in that I agree.  Thanks for suggestion to make getters const functions, I know what it means,but it didn't occure to me to use it there.  I'm just practising so to end a loop I use ctrl+d on linux.  Thanks about pointing on istream failures, I haven't thought about that much, but it sure is interesting problem to solve.  Can you please explain this for loop (or how is it called?), 'cause I didn't come accros it before    for(worker w; w.input(x); vec_workers.push_back(w));

Comment: @cppdisp, You are welcome. As for the loop... Please see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for ... The first part is executed once. The Second is always executed and tested as a boolean, should it test false, the loop breaks.(istream can be tested as a boolean. The third is always executed ....

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that istream can be tested as boolean. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I prefer working with pointers for personal reasons beyond the scope of your question.

To simply *add* objects of another class (somewhat misleading) decide if you want your vector to own those objects, hold a reference or a pointer to them.

In your implementation you create an object, then copy it in the vector.

```
worker temp;
while(temp.worker::input(x))
vec_workers.push_back(temp);
```

Holding a pointer is a different approach:

```
auto tmp = std::unique_ptr<worker>(new worker(x));
vec_workers.push_back(std::move(tmp));
```

Here you allocate once on the heap, and hold a pointer to it (the vector owns it). Same approach more or less with shared/smart pointers.

References are a bit more tricky and require the use of `std::reference_wrapper`.

You could also simply copy the object in the vector right away.

```
workers.push_back(std::move(worker(x));
```

Or work with raw pointers `std::vector<worker*> workers;`

Comment: Thanks on your suggestions. Regarding your first solution, how should I modify destructor ( do I need to do it at all) since I'm allocating memory on heap? I'm a beginer and as far as I know for every new must be a delete...

Comment: you don't need to if you use `std::unique_ptr`. Using the `new` operator without a smart pointer, you would need to use `delete`, but you can also use stack pointers. Deleting (manual memory management) can take many forms, along the lines of `std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), std::default_delete<Type>());`

Answer (score 0):

As I see here, the objects aren't of different classes, or am I mistaking.

They might have different constructors, but still not different classes.

Using a specific vector class for a type is kind of useless, but more readable I suppose.

You can't make a vector of multiple classes, as this isn't possible due to vector syntax.

As you see, you declare a vector using

```
    vector <type>
```

, not

```
    vector <type,...>
```

So you can only have vectors of a single type.

Also, if you could make a vector of multiple classes, that would screw up the size, as it would increase by different amounts depending on what class of object you put in it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to employ polymorphism and inheritance to get this to work. Objects of different types can technically not be added to a vector but inheritance and polymorphism can make it look like it is.

So you could have a vector like so

```
vector<BaseClass*> vec;
```

And push objects of derived classes to it.  Many modern programming languages have all classes derived from a common "object" class to make this and other things possible

Comment: It looks like you misunderstood me. Vector  vec_workers will be filled just with objects of type worker. I'm just looking for different implementation of my code. Sorry for misleading you, I'll edit my question to make it more clear.